# What's wrong with my dynamic programming algorithm with memoization?

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming, memoization

*Sorry about my poor English. If there is anything that you don't understand, please tell me so that I can give you more information that 'make sence'.

**This is first time asking question in Stackoverflow. I've searched some rules for asking questions correctly here, but there should be something I missed. I welcome all feedback.

I'm currently solving algorithm problems to improve my skill, and I'm struggling with one question for three days. This question is from https://algospot.com/judge/problem/read/RESTORE , but since this page is in KOREAN, I tried to translate it in English.

**Question**  
If there are 'k' pieces of partial strings given, calculate shortest string that includes all partial strings.
All strings consist only lowercase alphabets.
If there are more than 1 result strings that satisfy all conditions with same length, choose any string.

**Input** 
In the first line of input, number of test case 'C'(C<=50) is given.
For each test case, number of partial string 'k'(1<=k<=15) is given in the first line, and in next k lines partial strings are given.
Length of partial string is between 1 to 40.

**Output** 
For each testcase, print shortest string that includes all partial strings.

**Sample Input** 
3 
3 
geo 
oji 
jing 
2 
world 
hello 
3 
abrac 
cadabra 
dabr

**Sample Output** 
geojing 
helloworld 
cadabrac

And here is my code. My code seems to work perfect with Sample Inputs, and when I made test inputs for my own and tested, everything worked fine. But when I submit this code, they say my code is 'wrong'.

Please tell me what is wrong with my code. You don't need to tell me whole fixed code, I just need sample inputs that causes error with my code. Added code description to make my code easier to understand.

**Code Description**

Saved all input partial strings in vector '*stringParts*'.
Saved current shortest string result in global variable '*answer*'.
Used '*cache*' array for memoization - to skip repeated function call.

Algorithm I designed to solve this problem is divided into two function -
 restore() & eraseOverlapped().

restore() function calculates shortest string that includes all partial strings in '*stringParts*'.
Result of resotre() is saved in '*answer*'.

For restore(), there are three parameters - '*curString*', '*selected*' and '*last*'.
'*curString*' stands for currently selected and overlapped string result.
'*selected*' stands for currently selected elements of 'stringParts'. Used bitmask to make my algorithm concise.
'*last*' stands for last selected element of '*stringParts*' for making '*curString*'.

eraseOverlapped() function does preprocessing - it deletes elements of '*stringParts*' that can be completly included to other elements before executing restore().

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#define MAX 15
using namespace std;

int k;
string answer; // save shortest result string

vector<string> stringParts;
bool cache[MAX + 1][(1 << MAX) + 1]; //[last selected string][set of selected strings in Bitmask]

void restore(string curString, int selected=0, int last=0) {
    //base case 1
    if (selected == (1 << k) - 1) {
        if (answer.empty() || curString.length() < answer.length()) 
            answer = curString;
        return;
    }
    //base case 2 - memoization
    bool& ret = cache[last][selected];
    if (ret != false) return;

    for (int next = 0; next < k; next++) {
        string checkStr = stringParts[next];
        if (selected & (1 << next)) continue;

        if (curString.empty())
            restore(checkStr, selected + (1 << next), next + 1);
        else {
            int check = false;
            //count max overlapping area of two strings and overlap two strings.
            for (int i = (checkStr.length() > curString.length() ? curString.length() : checkStr.length())
                ; i > 0; i--) {
                if (curString.substr(curString.size()-i, i) == checkStr.substr(0, i)) {
                    restore(curString + checkStr.substr(i, checkStr.length()-i), selected + (1 << next), next + 1);
                    check = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!check) { // if there aren't any overlapping area
                restore(curString + checkStr, selected + (1 << next), next + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    ret = true;
}
//check if there are strings that can be completely included by other strings, and delete that string.
void eraseOverlapped() {
    //arranging string vector in ascending order of string length
    int vectorLen = stringParts.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < vectorLen - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < vectorLen; j++) {
            if (stringParts[i].length() < stringParts[j].length()) {
                string temp = stringParts[i];
                stringParts[i] = stringParts[j];
                stringParts[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    //deleting included strings
    vector<string>::iterator iter;
    for (int i = 0; i < vectorLen-1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < vectorLen; j++) {
            if (stringParts[i].find(stringParts[j]) != string::npos) {
                iter = stringParts.begin() + j;
                stringParts.erase(iter);
                j--;
                vectorLen--;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int C;
    cin >> C; // testcase
    for (int testCase = 0; testCase < C; testCase++) {
        cin >> k; // number of partial strings
        memset(cache, false, sizeof(cache)); // initializing cache to false
        string inputStr;
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            cin >> inputStr;
            stringParts.push_back(inputStr);
        }
        eraseOverlapped();
        k = stringParts.size();

        restore("");
        cout << answer << endl;
        answer.clear();
        stringParts.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: @AshishMathew Thanks for your comment. I posted this question here because in link this kind of question belongs to stackoverflow. Please tell me if I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: @AshishMathew Code Review is for code that work that possibly could work better. In this case the code does not work and piecemaker is bug hunting. This may be a good question for Stack Overflow, haven't processed all of it yet, but it is certainly a bad question for Code Review.

Comment: @user4581301 Ok. Got it

Comment: @AshishMathew I'm sorry that link in my comment was crashed. Here is the link - [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165519/where-should-i-post-questions-about-algorithms-stack-overflow-or-software-engin)

Comment: @RSahu The question said 'If there are more than 1 result strings that satisfy all conditions with same length, choose any string'. This means both "geojing" and "ojingeo" can be answer - because both strings have length of 7.

Comment: If allowed by the assignment, you should consider using `std::sort` and `std::remove_if`. They are speedy and trustworthy. Why risk writing your own when you can use something tested by millions of programmers?

Comment: @user4581301 thanks, user4581301. I've learned about sort before but forgot to apply it in this algorithm. I'll try to apply it in further algorithm. And I didn't know remove_if exists. Should learn about it when I finish solving this problem. Thanks.

Comment: @xskxzr thanks, xskxzr. If I use bool ret instead of bool& ret, I think I have to add 1 more line in the code - cache[last][selected] = ret; . I thought using reference type could make my code concise. Please give comment if I'm wrong.

Comment: My mistaken. I didn't fully look at your code.

Comment: Your approach is greedy algorithm. But it does not guarantee the optimal result. Sometimes, even when you can combine two strings into smaller one, it is better not to do so. Consider these strings. abc cde abccde. If you combine first two string, then you are ruined.

Comment: @Parker Thanks, Parker. I also noticed the problem you mentioned, and that's the reason I put eraseOverlapped() function in my algorithm. Because I deleted strings that can be completely included to other string, abc and cde will be deleted before calling restore() - which means only abccde will remain. Please give comment if I'm missing something.

Comment: Then how about these strings? abc cde bccd..

Comment: @Parker Now this is why my algorithm is wrong. Since adding additional logic to my algorithm to solve your example will not make my algorithm concise, I think I have to re-design algorithm completely. Thank you for your help, Parker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Everyone who tried to help me solve this problem. I actually solved this problem with few changes on my previous algorithm. These are main changes.

1. In my previous algorithm I saved result of restore() in global variable *'answer'* since restore() didn't return anything, but in new algorithm since restore() returns mid-process answer string I no longer need to use *'answer'*.
2. Used string type cache instead of bool type cache. I found out using bool cache for memoization in this algorithm was useless.
3. Deleted *'curString'* parameter from restore(). Since what we only need during recursive call is one previously selected partial string, *'last'* can replace role of *'curString'*.

**CODE**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#define MAX 15
using namespace std;

int k;

vector<string> stringParts;
string cache[MAX + 1][(1 << MAX) + 1];

string restore(int selected = 0, int last = -1) {
    if (selected == (1 << k) - 1) {
        return stringParts[last];
    }

    if (last == -1) {
        string ret = "";
        for (int next = 0; next < k; next++) {
            string resultStr = restore(selected + (1 << next), next);
            if (ret.empty() || ret.length() > resultStr.length())
                ret = resultStr;
        }
        return ret;
    }

    string& ret = cache[last][selected];
    if (!ret.empty()) {
        cout << "cache used in [" << last << "][" << selected << "]" << endl;
        return ret;
    }

    string curString = stringParts[last];
    for (int next = 0; next < k; next++) {
        if (selected & (1 << next)) continue;

        string checkStr = restore(selected + (1 << next), next);
        int check = false;
        string resultStr;
        for (int i = (checkStr.length() > curString.length() ? curString.length() : checkStr.length())
            ; i > 0; i--) {
            if (curString.substr(curString.size() - i, i) == checkStr.substr(0, i)) {
                resultStr = curString + checkStr.substr(i, checkStr.length() - i);
                check = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!check)
            resultStr = curString + checkStr;

        if (ret.empty() || ret.length() > resultStr.length())
            ret = resultStr;
    }
    return ret;
}

void EraseOverlapped() {
    int vectorLen = stringParts.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < vectorLen - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < vectorLen; j++) {
            if (stringParts[i].length() < stringParts[j].length()) {
                string temp = stringParts[i];
                stringParts[i] = stringParts[j];
                stringParts[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    vector<string>::iterator iter;
    for (int i = 0; i < vectorLen - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < vectorLen; j++) {
            if (stringParts[i].find(stringParts[j]) != string::npos) {
                iter = stringParts.begin() + j;
                stringParts.erase(iter);
                j--;
                vectorLen--;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int C;
    cin >> C;
    for (int testCase = 0; testCase < C; testCase++) {
        cin >> k;
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX + 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < (1 << MAX) + 1; j++)
                cache[i][j] = "";
        }
        string inputStr;
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            cin >> inputStr;
            stringParts.push_back(inputStr);
        }
        EraseOverlapped();
        k = stringParts.size();
        string resultStr = restore();
        cout << resultStr << endl;
        stringParts.clear();
    }
}
```

This algorithm is much slower than the 'ideal' algorithm that the book I'm studying suggests, but it was fast enough to pass this question's time limit.

Answer (score 0):

After determining which string-parts can be removed from the list since they are contained in other string-parts, one way to model this problem might be as the "[taxicab ripoff problem](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5e97/dc9a5ed1a795f68fbe23790a3d4783638a51.pdf)" problem (or Max TSP), where each potential length reduction by overlap is given a positive weight. Considering that the input size in the question is very small, it seems likely that they expect a near brute-force solution, with possibly some heuristic and backtracking or other form of memoization.